# In a flow, collection variable contains what it is supposed to but skips decision outcome, how would you handle it?

Tags: visual-workflow, loop

[image]"Open" Outcome conditions Does Require Record Changed to meet criteria: true {!contactsStageText} ([Open]) Contains Open Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met:

EDIT: contactsStageText was text previously, later changed to Picklist collection variable to match to the record type to update. Now all the collection variable and variables going to the decision element are picklist variable. I am using contains in decision element to see if the collection picklist variable contains "Opt-out" first and others later.

I think this debug of flow says it all, but I am not sure why would it happen as I am using contains to see if the collection variable contain Open or not but, debug shows even though there was open in collection variable this decision path was skipped. What am I doing wrong here?[image]
Overall flow looks like this. [image]

Comment: Can you add detail of the collection variable and how it is populated, plus the condition element please? Screenshots would be adequate.

Comment: I hope the Screenshots will help to diagnose what I might have done wrong just to get default outcome.

Comment: What is the type for "contactstage"? Please [edit] to add this detail. Is it a picklist?

Comment: I suspect it is because you are testing a string value against a picklist value. Look at [this unofficialsf.com resource](https://unofficialsf.com/extract-text-from-email-fields-picklist-fields-and-more-with-the-extracttextfromnontextfield-action/).

Comment: I had also tried with string, but I will try again, thank you @PhilW for the suggestion and help.

Comment: at the start of decision as well as at the end I have Picklist record types in the middle while making decision I need to convert collection picklist variable to Text data just to decide and later update picklist from that decision. I now find trapped as I do not see any thing to convert collection picklist variable to Test record type to use in decision. I read the post that you referred to was too complex for me to understand, that looks like I have to install a package in sfdc org just to use decision element of Flow ):

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131736/discussion-between-tough-and-phil-w).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Do one of the following:

- Use a **Text** Collection and not a **Picklist** Collection for your `accountstagecollection`. Continue to ADD your `contactstage` value as you are doing, then later in your *Decision* element you will be comparing the same data types.
- Create some single **Picklist** type variables - one for each possible picklist value. Assign the appropriate value to them *(e.g., `picklistVariable_Optout` EQUALS Opt-out)*, then use those as the *Value* in each of your *Decision* element Outcome comparisons *(e.g., `accountstagecollection` CONTAINS `picklistVariable_Optout`)*.

---

This intrigued me greatly, so I set up a test Flow (which I would be happy to share...somehow) to attempt to cover as many options that I could think of.

- A Text field and a Picklist field were added to the Account object.
- Picklist values were `Open`, `Opt-out` and `Demo Booked`.
- On an individual Account record, I added the same value in the Text field as I chose for the Picklist field. (E.g., for Record 1 both new fields had the value of "Open", for Record 2 they both were "Opt-out")
- In the Flow, all of the Account records were retrieved, looped through, and the values of these two fields added to Flow Variables as follows:

| Value from this field | Into this type Flow variable | Variable name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Text | Text Collection | `textFromTextCollection` |
|  | Picklist Collection | `picklistFromTextCollection` |
|  | Text Single | `textSingle` |
| Picklist | Text Collection | `textFromPicklistCollection` |
|  | Picklist Collection | `picklistFromPicklistCollection` |
|  | Picklist Single | `picklistSingle` |

*The single variables were a curiosity - as I ADDed to them in each loop, thus creating one long, continuous string.*

- Next, successive *Decision* elements were placed to parse the various Collections and compare them in different ways

  1. `textFromTextCollection` CONTAINS *text*

     [image]
  2. `picklistFromTextCollection` CONTAINS *text*

     [image]
  3. `textFromPicklistCollection` CONTAINS *text*

     [image]
  4. `picklistFromPicklistCollection` CONTAINS *text*

     [image]

  > Numbers 1 and 3 - where the Collection variable was **Text** type - worked by following the correct Outcome.
  >
  > Numbers 2 and 4 - where the Collection variable was **Picklist** type - did NOT work and they followed the "Default" Outcome.

  5. `textSingle` CONTAINS *text*

     [image]
  6. `picklistSingle` CONTAINS *text*

     [image]

  > Curiously, both of these worked by following the correct Outcome path.

---

Finally (probably should have started here) I looked in *Salesforce Help > Docs > Automate Your Business Processes > Flow Operators in Decision and Pause Elements*:

**[Collection](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_operators_condition.htm&type=5#collection)**

Check whether a Collection resource's value contains or matches another value or resource.

| Operator | True if... | Supported Data Types |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Contains | An item in the collection that's selected for Resource contains the exact same value as Value | Resource of the same data type. |

**[Picklist](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_operators_condition.htm&type=5#picklist)**

Check whether  a Picklist resource's value matches or contains another value or resource.

> NOTE: These operators treat the resource’s value as a text value.

| Operator | True if... | Supported Data Types |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Contains | The value for Resource contains what's entered or selected for Value | - Picklist *is included in a long list of data types* |
|  | For example, if the value of `{!varPicklist}` is yellow-green, the condition `{!varPicklist}` **Contains** green evaluates to true |  |

---

The results of the test Flow match exactly with the documentation:

- When the *Collection* was of **Text** type and compared directly to text typed into the *Value* box, it worked.
- When the *Collection* was of **Picklist** type and compared directly to text typed into the *Value* box, it did NOT work.
- When the *Single (non-Collection)* variable was of **either** type and compared directly to text typed into the *Value* box, it worked.

---

So in order to test this further, I created three **Picklist** single variables to use essentially as constants *(you cannot create a Flow Constant of Picklist type)*. A new first element in the Flow set these variables:

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `picklistVariable_Open` | Open |
| `picklistVariable_Optout` | Opt-out |
| `picklistVariable_DemoBooked` | Demo Booked |

*Screenshot:*
[image]

Next I added a *Decision* element to compare one of the **Picklist** Collection variables to the new **Picklist** single "constant" variables:

- `picklistFromPicklistCollection` CONTAINS *picklist Single variable*

  [image]

...**it worked!**

---

**EDIT**

I just re-read your chat discussion with @PhilW and discovered something you said that did not register with me the first time I read it:

> [A]t the start of decision as well as at the end I have Picklist record types in the middle while making decision I need to convert collection picklist variable to Text data just to decide and later update picklist from that decision. I now find trapped...

So in your specific case I would suggest the second option above - especially since it is Record Types and thus is a restricted Picklist, thus making it easy to create a Flow Picklist variable for each possible value.

Comment: Thank you @Moonpie for your detailed explanation and lots of effort you have put to explain. I am sincerely thankful to your generosity and helpfulness. I will put myself to test  this for myself and get better understanding. I am so happy that we have a community to help each other.