# Some one good in flow help me please, the decision element is always taking the default path

Tags: visual-workflow, loop

Lets say I have contact1 and contact2 who have picklist stages [ New, Open, Prepecting, Nurture] in a account. Account also have similar stages form picklist. I would like to align the furthest stage of contacts in a account to the account stage with the use of flow. In a flow I use loop to pass all the contacts from account id which triggers flow to put all stages in one text variable  "textvariablefordecision" using add function in assignment. I take this variable out of the loop to decision element and decide using contains function of decision element. If the textvariablefordecision contains first the highest stage then I will assign the account stage to that stage else check for other stages in textvariablefordecision.

I have this Text variable which I will later user in decision textvariablefordecision where I collect all the possible outcomes with the help of add function in assignment element.

Decision element uses contains function to see if on of the stages are there in textvariablefordecision after collection in loop.  Luckily it contains eg. Demo BookedOpen in textvariablefordecision.
[where I have the Screenshot][1]
here is what I find strange about the outcome of contains function or my whole flow is that the decision element skips this outcome and goes further to default path rendering all my flow use less. Here is what I found while debugging flow.

````
Outcome conditions

Does Require Record Changed to meet criteria: true
{!textvariablefordecision} (Demo BookedOpen) Contains Demo Booked
Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met: ```


*What have I tried: 

Tried using collection text variable, tried using picklist collection variable. What I always find is here in the debug or in variable I have what is required to come to a decision but decision element skips this outcome to take the path of default outcome. 
It have been bugging from days. I really really begging for your expertise on its resolution. It could be a X-mas gift to me :) *


  [1]: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/362766/in-a-flow-collection-variable-contains-what-it-is-supposed-to-but-skips-decisio
````

Comment: can you provide some screenshots of the flow related to logic  with sample input and expextations.

Comment: I know yesterday's question hasn't been answered, but please don't simply ask a new question about the same thing.